# SQL Server Generate a Time Series view showing historic data for any given day

Tags: sql, sql-server, time-series, type-2-dimension

I want to view historic data for any given day in a more performing/faster way.

**I have the following dummy tables and dummy data:**

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.DateDim (

  [Date] date,

  DayNumber int

  )

-- insert dummy values

  INSERT INTO dbo.DateDim (

  [Date],

  [DayNumber]

  )

  VALUES ('2020-01-01',1),

  ('2020-01-02',2),

  ('2020-01-03',3),

  ('2020-01-04',4),

  ('2020-01-05',5)

 

-- create productHistory table

CREATE TABLE dbo.ProductHistory (

ProductId int,

Price int,

[Status] int,

ValidFrom datetime,

ValidTo datetime

)

 

-- insert dummy values

INSERT INTO dbo.ProductHistory (

ProductId,

Price,

[Status],

ValidFrom,

ValidTo

)

VALUES (

1,230,2,'2020-01-01 00:00:00:00','2020-01-02 08:10:30:00'),(1,250,3,'2020-01-02 08:11:00:00','2020-01-03 11:10:31:00'),

(1,235,2,'2020-01-03 11:12:34:00','2020-01-04 11:12:34:00'),(1,285,4,'2020-01-04 11:14:36:00','9999-01-05 00:00:00:00'

)
```

Using the dbo.DateDim and the dbo.ProductHistory table, I want to see how data looks like for any given Day in a table in PowerBI.

**To achieve this, I did the following:**

```
-- my current logic

SELECT D.*, P.*

FROM dbo.DateDim AS D

INNER JOIN dbo.ProductHistory AS P

            ON D.Date >= P.ValidFrom and D.Date <= P.ValidTo

WHERE D.Date >= P.ValidFrom

AND D.Date <= P.ValidTo
```

**The issue** is that I have 100k unique rows in my data set with many columns. Generating a simple view in the way that I currently did gets me 100k (unique records in my table)*365 (days in a year)*7 (how many years I currently go back) = 255,5 million rows. The view takes too long to generate.

**My question therefore:** How do I accomplish this in a performing/fast way? As mentioned, the end goal is to click on a date filter in PowerBI, which allows you to see how the data looked like for any given day. I am open for other methods than a simple view.

Comment: Views can get rather expensive.  Perhaps you should consider a Table-Valued Function where you pass the desired date as a parameter.

Comment: Would this work for the PowerBI use case, and if yes, how? Would the [date] filter in my PowerBI report execute this table valued function, and then have a data set (for this date) returned for display? I am not that experienced with PowerBI

Comment: Can PowerBI pass parameters to a stored procedure? (I am also not that experienced with PowerBI but typically if a tool doesn't know how to use a table-valued function a fallback would be to call a stored procedure that is just a wrapper around the table-valued function call.)

Comment: Looks like you need better indexing: primary key on `DateDim (Date)` and non-clustered index on `ProductHistory (ValidFrom, ValidTo) INCLUDE (OtherColumnsHere)`